# VNC x0vncserver "password" parameter not working as expected

Tags: linux-mint, vnc

I'm trying hard to configure sort of "desktop sharing solution" on Linux Mint 19.2 MATE. I basically need a way for tech support to provide assistance for remote user on his very desktop.

The idea is when user needs help he contacts t-support, then presses magic icon on desktop which:

- generates and shows one time password for session (makepasswd -string 1234567890 -chars 8)
- initiates x0vncserver (tigervnc-scraping-server) with said password.

Then user supplies password to t-assistant, t-ass connects to user's desktop and helps him out.

The problem is that despite x0vncserver has two distinct params (password and passwordfile) it won't allow to connect with only "password" param specified with error "No password configured for VNC Auth" and I can't use vncpasswd util to configure password file because it won't allow me to supply desired password as parameter to this command

So any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's quite simple in Linux, actually. Linux allows to supply replies to vncpasswd prompts right away:

$ printf "MYPASSWORD\nMYPASSWORD\n\n" | vncpasswd